# Issue with DELETE method- PHP slim framework

Tags: php, slim

I have issue with DELETE method. Below is the code, where i am getting `404 error` for DELETE method. If i use `get` method instead of `delete`,  code executing properly. Please help me where i went wrong.

```
<?php
require "Slim/Slim.php";
require "NotORM/NotORM.php";
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=rest_trial', 'uname', 'passwd');
$db = new NotORM($pdo);

//DELETE method
$app->delete("/deletebook/:id", function ($id) use($app, $db) {
//$app->get("/deletebook/:id", function ($id) use($app, $db) {
$app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
$book = $db->books()->where("id", $id);
if ($book->fetch()) {
    $result = $book->delete();
    echo "Book deleted successfully";
}
else{
    echo "Book id $id does not exist";
}
});
$app->run();
```

Comment: if you look in the network tab of your browser console you can check if the method of your request is actually `DELETE`.

Answer (score 4):

If you look in the network tab of your browser console you can check if the method of your request is actually `DELETE`.

Some browsers do not support `PUT` and `DELETE` http request method.
Slim provide a method for that:

"*Unfortunately, modern browsers do not provide native support for HTTP DELETE requests. To work around this limitation, ensure your HTML form’s method attribute is “post”, then add a method override parameter to your HTML form like this:*"

```
<form action="/books/1" method="post">
    ... other form fields here...
    <input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="DELETE"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete Book"/>
</form>
```

"*If you are using Backbone.js or a command-line HTTP client, you may also override the HTTP method by using the X-HTTP-Method-Override header.*"